# MongoDB - Best way to store and read data

Tags: php, mongodb, database

I have a Mongo database .

I have two collection :

1. users
2. posts

User sending a post but question is here . Which way is better ?

1. Store Only user _id behind of post ( POST CREATOR).
2. Store user info like ( _id , name , username , ... ) behind of post .

In the first method we need to fetch user info from collection USERS .

In the second method we need to update all posts data that was sended by user Only when user updated profile info .

Which is better ?

Comment: The best way to store relational data is to store it in a relational database.

Comment: @Federkun are you mean first method is better ?

Comment: SO you have already agreed to go with 1st option.. And according to me too 1st is good

Answer (score 4):

Embedding one document in another is normal in MongoDB. I think the second way is better, because:

1-  you don't have to consider relation manually so its more cleaner

2- by choosing the first way you have to add one or more extra queries (performance issue)

Answer (score 4):

To find out the best way for your app, ask yourself these questions:

a) Is the nr of write (updates) query on user collection high or low? (probably is low)

b) Is the nr of read query on post colelction high or low? (probably is high)

c) How important is (user) data consistency?

Denormalization is a common approach in MongoDB. 
If nr of writes is less in comparison with nr of reads, denormalization of data by embedding data will produce better reads perfomance, but slower write performance, cause you need to write in more places. It matters to note that, inconsistency of data may occur, because in mongodb writes are not atomic only when writing on a single document.

By choosing solution #1, you will have slower reads on posts, because that needs to make other read query on user collection. Data consistency is guaranteed and you get also more flexibility.

By choosing solution #2 you will have faster reads on posts because everything is there, embedded, you have it in one query. But you will have slower user query updates. On this solution, data consistency is not guaranted, but this might not be a big problem in some apps when updates inconsistency can be treated later.
In here, you can embedd only parts that you need of the user data, not all, like only username (and _id) for example, if you need only the username to display it on the post.

If you have a very big dataset with lots of post, and less updates on user collection, lots of reads on post collection, and user data can contain inconsistencies which might occur and they are not criticaly important and can be fixed later, better solution is #2 with respect of performance.

An interesting article about schema design you can find it in [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-3).

Answer (score 2):

Surely read requests more than edit requests .

So if you use first method you have to add some query's to read data from collection and it Low-off your read performance .

Make sure second method is better .